# Unable to Compile Win32 Application

Tags: winapi, mingw

I'm trying to compile a Win32 application of mine, but am getting the following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.tex
t+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's what the compiler command looks like:

```
g++ -Wl,--subsystem,windows foo.cpp
```

It's strange, because I'm sure this used to work before. (At the time, though, I was using Windows XP.)

Note: I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit, using mingw32.

Comment: What does the prototype of your `WinMain()` function look like?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)`

Comment: That looks fine... try adding `-mwindows` to the compiler options. That's pretty far-fetched, but maybe the compiler doesn't use the right naming convention without that flag.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: I tried adding that before, and it didn't work :(.

Comment: @someguy, `WinMain()` is not `static` and is fully defined in `foo.cpp`, right?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Sorry about the late reply; yes, WinMain is not `static` and is defined in foo.cpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, **LPWSTR** lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

It should be:

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, **LPSTR** lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

So the sig does -not- match and the linker can't find it.

Comment: Good catch, but `WINAPI` should be preventing name-mangling based on parameter types, so I think this is a separate problem.

Comment: This actually fixed it. Thanks :). I don't know how I managed to write `LPWSTR` considering I copy-pasted it from MSDN :o. Edit: Ah, right, I was looking at the documentation for "Windows Embedded CE-based applications" -.-

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this, I suggest:

1. Compile and link separately, so you get an object file (use `g++ -c`)
2. Dump the list of exported names from said object file (use `nm` or `objdump`)